# Nurse scheduling model formulation in AMPL

Tags: job-scheduling, ampl, operations-research

I have been working on a Nurse scheduling problem in AMPL for the following conditions:

Total no. of Nurses=20

Total no. of shits= 3 #morning,day,night

Planning Horizon 7 days: let's say M T W R F Sa Su

Along with following constraints:

1. Max no. of working days in a week: 5
2. A rest days after 4 continuous
   night shifts.
3. Consecutive night and morning shifts are not allowed.
4. Demand per shift is 7 nurses.
5. A nurse can only work in one shift per day,  i.e. morning, night, day

Cost scenarios:

```
Morning shift: $12
Day shift: $13
Night shift : $15
```

Objective function is to minimize the cost of operation as per Nurse preferences.

Can anyone give me an idea of how this problem can be formulated ?

Answer (score 1):

So at first some things unusual in your problem definition:

1. This is not a real optimization problem, since your objective function is fixed per definition (every shift has 7 nurses, and every nurse has an equal price per shift)
2. In your Problem you defined 7 nurses per shift with a maimum of 5 working days. So you need 7 nurses on three shifts on seven days. This equals 147 nurse/shifts. But with the cap of five working days and only one shift per day, you just have 20 Nurses on 5 shifts, which equals to 100 nurse/shifts.

I've built the problem in Mathprog but the code should be more or less equal to AMPL. I've started with three sets for the nurses, days and shifts.

```
set shifts := {1,2,3};
set days := {1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
set nurses := {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20};
```

The shedule is defined as a set of binary variables:

```
var schedule{nurses, days, shifts}, binary;
```

The simple objective contains the sum of all nurse/shifts in this week with the related prices:

```
minimize cost: sum{i in nurses, j in days}(schedule[i,j,1]*c_morning+schedule[i,j,2]*c_day+schedule[i,j,3]*c_night);
```

To your first constraint one can limit the sum of all shifts per nurse to five, since there is only one shift per day possible:

```
s.t. working_days{n in nurses}:
sum{i in days, j in shifts}(schedule[n,i,j]) <= 5;
```

The restday is the hardest part of the problem. For simplicity I've created another set which just contains the days, where a nurse could have achived four night-shifts in a row. You can also formulate the constraint with the original set of days and exclude the first four days.

```
set nigth_days := {5,6,7};
    s.t. rest{n in nurses,i in nigth_days}:
    (schedule[n,i-4,3]+schedule[n,i-3,3]+schedule[n,i-2,3]+schedule[n,i-1,3]+sum{j in shifts}(schedule[n,i,j])) <= 4;
```

For not having a morning-shift after a night-shift I used the same attempt like for the rest days. The seventh day is excluded, since there is no eigth day where we can look for a morning-shift.

```
    set yester_days := {1,2,3,4,5,6};
s.t. night_morning{i in yester_days, n in nurses}:
(schedule[n,i,3]+schedule[n,i+1,1]) <= 1;
```

The demand of four nurses per shift should be met (I've reduced the number since more then 4 nurses are infeasible, due to the 5 shift limit)

```
s.t. demand_shift{i in days, j in shifts}:
sum{n in nurses}(schedule[n,i,j]) = 4;
```

The fifth constraint is to limit the shifts per day to a max of one.

```
s.t. one_shift{n in nurses, i in days}:
sum{ j in shifts}(schedule[n,i,j]) <= 1;
```

Comment: how can we accommodate the constraint to have a nurse not working consecutive shifts? E.g. a nurse working in Night shift on Monday cannot work the Morning shift on Tuesday

Answer (score 1):

```
set nurse; #no. of full time employees working in the facility
set days;  #planning horizon 
set shift; #no. of shift in a day
set S; #shift correseponding to the outsourced nurses
set D;#day corresponding to the outsourced nurses
set N;#


# ith nurse working on day j

# j starts from Monday (j=1), Tuesday( j=2), Wednesday (j=3), Thursday(j=4), Friday(j=5), Saturday(j=6), Sunday(j=7)
#s be the shift as morning, day and night  



param availability{i in nurse, j in days};
param costpershift{i in nurse, j in days, s in shift};
param outcost{n in N, l in D, m in S};

var nurseavailability{i in nurse,j in days,s in shift} binary; # = 1 if nurse i is available on jth day working on sth shift, 0 otherwise
var outsourced{n in N, l in D, m in S} integer;


#Objective function

minimize Cost: sum{i in nurse, j in days, s in shift} costpershift[i,j,s]*nurseavailability[i,j,s]+ sum{ n in N, l in D, m in S}outcost[n,l,m]*outsourced[n,l,m];


#constraints

#maximum no. of shifts per day

subject to maximum_shifts_perday {i in nurse,j in days}:
 sum{s in shift} nurseavailability[i,j,s]*availability[i,j] <= 1;

#maximum no. of working says a week

subject to maximum_days_of_work {i in nurse}:  
sum{j in days,s in shift} availability[i,j]*nurseavailability[i,j,s]<=5; #maximum working days irrespective of shifts

# rest days after night shifts

subject to rest_days_after_night_shift{i in nurse}:  
sum{j in days} availability[i,j]*nurseavailability[i,j,3]<=4;


#demand per shift

subject to supply{j in days, s in shift, l in D, m in S}: 
sum{i in nurse} availability[i,j]*nurseavailability[i,j,s] + sum{n in N} outsourced[n,l,m]=7;


#outsourcing only works well when there is more variability in supply.
#increasing the staff no. would be effective for reducing the cost variability in demand.
#considering a budget of $16,000 per week
#outsourcing constraints: a maximum of 20 nurses can be outsourced per shift
# no. of fulltime employees=30
#demand is 7 nurses per shift
#the average variability 
#all nurses are paid equally @ $12 per hour.
#cost of an outsourced shift is $144.
#cost of morning shift is $96.
#cost of day shift is $104.
#cost of night shift is $120.

data;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           


#set nurse ordered:=    nurse1  nurse2  nurse3  nurse4  nurse5  nurse6  nurse7  nurse8  
#nurse9 nurse10 nurse11 nurse12 nurse13 nurse14 nurse15 nurse16 nurse17 
#nurse18    nurse19 nurse20;

set nurse:= 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30;

#set days ordered:= Monday Tuesday  Wednesday Thursday Friday Saturday Sunday;

set days:= 1 2 3 4 5 6 7;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           

#set shift ordered:=    Morning Day Night;

set shift:= 1 2 3;  

set D:= 1 2 3 4 5 6 7; #outsourced days
set S:=1 2 3; #outshit 
set N := 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20;




   param outcost

   [*,*,1]:
                         1     2   3   4   5   6   7:=

                      1  144  144 144 144 144 144 144
                      2  144  144 144 144 144 144 144
                      3  144  144 144 144 144 144 144
                      4  144  144 144 144 144 144 144
                      5  144  144 144 144 144 144 144
                      6  144  144 144 144 144 144 144
                      7  144  144 144 144 144 144 144
                      8  144  144 144 144 144 144 144
                      9  144  144 144 144 144 144 144
                     10  144  144 144 144 144 144 144
                     11  144  144 144 144 144 144 144
                     12  144  144 144 144 144 144 144
                     13  144  144 144 144 144 144 144
                     14  144  144 144 144 144 144 144
                     15  144  144 144 144 144 144 144
                     16  144  144 144 144 144 144 144
                     17  144  144 144 144 144 144 144
                     18  144  144 144 144 144 144 144
                     19  144  144 144 144 144 144 144
                     20  144  144 144 144 144 144 144


    [*,*,2]:
                            1     2   3   4   5   6   7:=

                      1  144  144 144 144 144 144 144
                      2  144  144 144 144 144 144 144
                      3  144  144 144 144 144 144 144
                      4  144  144 144 144 144 144 144
                      5  144  144 144 144 144 144 144
                      6  144  144 144 144 144 144 144
                      7  144  144 144 144 144 144 144
                      8  144  144 144 144 144 144 144
                      9  144  144 144 144 144 144 144
                     10  144  144 144 144 144 144 144
                     11  144  144 144 144 144 144 144
                     12  144  144 144 144 144 144 144
                     13  144  144 144 144 144 144 144
                     14  144  144 144 144 144 144 144
                     15  144  144 144 144 144 144 144
                     16  144  144 144 144 144 144 144
                     17  144  144 144 144 144 144 144
                     18  144  144 144 144 144 144 144
                     19  144  144 144 144 144 144 144
                     20  144  144 144 144 144 144 144

     [*,*,3]:

                          1     2   3   4   5   6   7:=

                      1  144  144 144 144 144 144 144
                      2  144  144 144 144 144 144 144
                      3  144  144 144 144 144 144 144
                      4  144  144 144 144 144 144 144
                      5  144  144 144 144 144 144 144
                      6  144  144 144 144 144 144 144
                      7  144  144 144 144 144 144 144
                      8  144  144 144 144 144 144 144
                      9  144  144 144 144 144 144 144
                     10  144  144 144 144 144 144 144
                     11  144  144 144 144 144 144 144
                     12  144  144 144 144 144 144 144
                     13  144  144 144 144 144 144 144
                     14  144  144 144 144 144 144 144
                     15  144  144 144 144 144 144 144
                     16  144  144 144 144 144 144 144
                     17  144  144 144 144 144 144 144
                     18  144  144 144 144 144 144 144
                     19  144  144 144 144 144 144 144
                     20  144  144 144 144 144 144 144;






   param availability:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
            1          2        3           4          5        6         7 :=  

    1       0          0        0           0          0        0         0                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
    2       1          1        1           1          1        1         1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
    3       1          1        1           1          1        1         1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
    4       1          1        1           1          1        1         1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
    5       1          1        1           1          1        1         1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
    6       1          1        1           1          1        1         1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
    7       1          0        1           1          1        1         1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
    8       1          1        1           1          1        1         1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
    9       1          1        1           1          1        1         1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
    10      1          1        1           1          1        1         1 
    11      1          1        1           1          1        1         1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
    12      1          1        1           1          1        1         1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
    13      1          1        1           1          1        1         1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
    14      1          1        1           1          1        1         1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
    15      1          1        1           1          1        1         1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
    16      1          1        1           1          1        1         1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
    17      0          1        1           1          1        1         1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
    18      1          1        1           1          1        1         1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
    19      1          1        1           1          1        1         1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
    20      1          1        1           1          1        1         1
    21      1          1        1           1          1        1         1 
    22      1          1        1           1          1        1         1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
    23      1          1        1           1          1        1         1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
    24      1          1        1           1          1        1         1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
    25      1          1        1           1          1        1         1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
    26      1          1        1           1          1        1         1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
    27      1          1        1           1          1        1         1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
    28      1          1        1           1          1        1         1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
    29      1          1        1           1          1        1         1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
    30      1          1        1           1          1        1         1;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    




param costpershift:= 


[*,*,1]:     1          2        3           4         5        6          7 := 


    1       96         96       96          96         96       96        96                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
    2       96         96       96          96         96       96        96                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
    3       96         96       96          96         96       96        96                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
    4       96         96       96          96         96       96        96                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
    5       96         96       96          96         96       96        96                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
    6       96         96       96          96         96       96        96                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
    7       96         96       96          96         96       96        96                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
    8       96         96       96          96         96       96        96                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
    9       96         96       96          96         96       96        96                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
    10      96         96       96          96         96       96        96    
    11      96         96       96          96         96       96        96                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
    12      96         96       96          96         96       96        96                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
    13      96         96       96          96         96       96        96                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
    14      96         96       96          96         96       96        96                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
    15      96         96       96          96         96       96        96                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
    16      96         96       96          96         96       96        96                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
    17      96         96       96          96         96       96        96                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
    18      96         96       96          96         96       96        96                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
    19      96         96       96          96         96       96        96                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
    20      96         96       96          96         96       96        96
    21      96         96       96          96         96       96        96                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
    22      96         96       96          96         96       96        96                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
    23      96         96       96          96         96       96        96                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
    24      96         96       96          96         96       96        96                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
    25      96         96       96          96         96       96        96                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
    26      96         96       96          96         96       96        96                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
    27      96         96       96          96         96       96        96                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
    28      96         96       96          96         96       96        96                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
    29      96         96       96          96         96       96        96                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
    30      96         96       96          96         96       96        96





  [*,*,2] : 1          2        3           4          5        6         7 :=      


    1       104        104      104         104        104      104       104                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
    2       104        104      104         104        104      104       104                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
    3       104        104      104         104        104      104       104                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
    4       104        104      104         104        104      104       104                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
    5       104        104      104         104        104      104       104                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
    6       104        104      104         104        104      104       104                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
    7       104        104      104         104        104      104       104                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
    8       104        104      104         104        104      104       104                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
    9       104        104      104         104        104      104       104                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
    10      104        104      104         104        104      104       104   
    11      104        104      104         104        104      104       104                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
    12      104        104      104         104        104      104       104                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
    13      104        104      104         104        104      104       104                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
    14      104        104      104         104        104      104       104                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
    15      104        104      104         104        104      104       104                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
    16      104        104      104         104        104      104       104                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
    17      104        104      104         104        104      104       104                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
    18      104        104      104         104        104      104       104                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
    19      104        104      104         104        104      104       104                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
    20      104        104      104         104        104      104       104
    21      104        104      104         104        104      104       104                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
    22      104        104      104         104        104      104       104                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
    23      104        104      104         104        104      104       104                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
    24      104        104      104         104        104      104       104                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
    25      104        104      104         104        104      104       104                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
    26      104        104      104         104        104      104       104                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
    27      104        104      104         104        104      104       104                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
    28      104        104      104         104        104      104       104                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
    29      104        104      104         104        104      104       104                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
    30      104        104      104         104        104      104       104



  [*,*,3] :  1         2         3          4          5        6         7 :=  


    1       120        120      120         120        120      120       120                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
    2       120        120      120         120        120      120       120                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
    3       120        120      120         120        120      120       120                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
    4       120        120      120         120        120      120       120                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
    5       120        120      120         120        120      120       120                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
    6       120        120      120         120        120      120       120                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
    7       120        120      120         120        120      120       120                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
    8       120        120      120         120        120      120       120                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
    9       120        120      120         120        120      120       120                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
    10      120        120      120         120        120      120       120   
    11      120        120      120         120        120      120       120                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
    12      120        120      120         120        120      120       120                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
    13      120        120      120         120        120      120       120                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
    14      120        120      120         120        120      120       120                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
    15      120        120      120         120        120      120       120                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
    16      120        120      120         120        120      120       120                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
    17      120        120      120         120        120      120       120                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
    18      120        120      120         120        120      120       120                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
    19      120        120      120         120        120      120       120                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
    20      120        120      120         120        120      120       120
    21      120        120      120         120        120      120       120                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
    22      120        120      120         120        120      120       120                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
    23      120        120      120         120        120      120       120                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
    24      120        120      120         120        120      120       120                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
    25      120        120      120         120        120      120       120                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
    26      120        120      120         120        120      120       120                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
    27      120        120      120         120        120      120       120                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
    28      120        120      120         120        120      120       120                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
    29      120        120      120         120        120      120       120                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
    30      120        120      120         120        120      120       120;
```

Comment: how can we accommodate the constraint to have a nurse not working consecutive shifts? E.g. a nurse working in Night shift on Monday cannot work the Morning shift on Tuesday